USB bandwidth limit verification
I am working on a project involving 2 sets of stereo camera pairs and I am trying to sync them all together. I have developed the sync board that generates PWM at the desired frequency to trigger each camera hardware trigger pins. Due to some limitation of the project, I have to use USB cameras and can't use other protocol but I have ensured that all camera are connected through USB3.0 port (my setup only have one USB3.0 root controller as well) through a USB3.0 hub
The desired operating specs are one stereo pair (camera A)with 1600x1300 resolution with 8-bit greyscale image at 60fps and the other stereo pair (camera B) with 640x512 resolution with 16-bit images at 60fps. While the calculated expected bandwidth is around 2.6 Gbit/s which is below the rated 5 Gbit/s of USB3.0 but I assume that there are some overheads so I digress there. I went a try different combination of resolution and framerate settings for both camera to see what works.
A combination of resolution and rates I found that works is for camera A 1280x720 res with 8-bit greyscale at 60fps and for camera B 640x512 res with 16-bit greyscale at 60fps which is expected to use 1.5Gbit/s. I would like to retain the max resolution of the camera A at 1600x1300 so reducing the framerate to around 30 fps also works. However, due to the nature of camera B, reducing the rate to 30fps degrades the quality so camera B needs to be triggered at 60fps.
y next approach now is to have the camera pairs triggered but PWM signal with different frequencies but still synced through their rising edges and being dividers of each others (60fps for camera B and 20fps for camera A). This becomes camera A at 1600x1300 at 8-bit at 20fps and camera B at 640x512 at 16-bit at 60fps. However, testing this configuration still results in USB bandwidth issue although it is expected to only need 1.3Gbit/s. I would like to ask if my assumption of it being a bandwidth issue correct and if so, why does the configuration with 60fps for both which uses 1.5Gbit/s works while the 60fps+20fps configuration which expected to use 1.3Gbit/s not work? Is there extra overhead for high resolution that does not scale with the actual value for the image resolution?
